# .Net web browser for windows mobile

Tags: c#, java, visual-studio, mobile, browser

I would like to start mobile developing.

I have done many research about how to create own web browser for windows mobile 6.5 and Windows CE in VS2008, but I can only find WM 7 everywhere by using silverlight. Are these devices support the silverlight, and allow me to create a web browser with visual studio 2008?

Is it even possible? Or which can be a better way to do it?

---

I also have some java script, what I would like to use. As far as I know, if the browser support the java, it's possible to run it, but what's the matter, if I create my own browser? Could I use these scripts?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the WebBrowser control from .NET Compact Framework.

Oh, and java and javascript are two different things.